# How do I check that the encrypted /swap partition is unlocked on Fedora 15?

Tags: troubleshooting, encryption, fedora-15

Background: I've upgraded from F11 to F15. This is a dual boot setup with Windows on the first partition, then /boot and LVM the next two partitions. The last LVM is then divided into /swap and /. To enable encryption, it is necessary to do so for both.

During startup I "accidentally" discovered the boot process output by pressing the arrow-up key. The boot output stopped and presented a second prompt (after a first graphical prompt) asking for the /swap passphrase. If I leave this, the system will eventually continue the boot process. Yet, I notice a few "failed" flags for things like cryptsetup, WLM (it goes too fast to write more than this; When I read the boot.log in the former case none of these failed flags appear and also the cryptsetup and WLM are not in the log.)

As I am ironing out errors after install, and I see these errors in the output, it leads me to ask, 
How can I check /swap is properly unlocked?

Comment: A "Meta topic" follow-up. I've spent two days on this installation. With the most of my time trying to get the backup DVD of F11 to mount. If you read this post and wonder, "what's the question?". I'm sorry. Each of the past few times I installed Linux, I've experienced a limbo period from the "first attempt" to install and when I know if the situation is nominal. Until I resolve what encryption is doing, and get my DVD to mount, I won't know if I have to reinstall. %-(

Comment: :-/ even simpler question.

Comment: I deleted the comment about plymouthd in the above question because it was not what I thought it was, and it seems [its not](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/plymouth/+bug/531331/comments/14) what [it thinks it is.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plymouth_%28software%29) %-)

Answer (score 0):

top

Top shows the swap space. I checked this both when leaving the system alone to boot by itself and by interrupting the background process and entering both values myself. The difference was obvious.

Answer (score 0):

The following should let you know exactly what swap you have 'on' and where it is.

`cat /proc/swaps`